# Save int as a char?

Tags: c, types, range

I'm trying to save an integer as a character.

```
char i = 80;
printf("0x%x", i);
```

The above code displays 0x50 (1 byte). But if the value is above 128, it prints a 4 byte value.

```
char i = 130;
printf("0x%x", i); // this prints 0xffffff82
```

How can I store the integer value as just 1 byte if the value is greater than 128 (print just 82 instead of ffffff82 in second example) ?

Comment: use `unsigned char i = 130;`

Comment: The `%x` format specifier will print a hexadeimal value. I believe `i` is being promoted, so you are printing an integer, not a 8-bit octet. That's why you are seeing the `0xffffff82`. You will also have to worry about `int` -> `char` truncations (in the general case).

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior on systems where `char` type is signed: negative values of `char` get sign-expanded to the size of an `int`.

If you would like to print the last eight bits, you could mask with `0xFF`, like this:

```
printf("0x%x", i & 0xFF); // this prints 80
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/nwuQIq).

An alternative approach is to use `unsigned char`. This would avoid sign extension for 8-bit numbers with the most significant bit set to `1`.